# unobstructed hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Why is a smooth complex hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree 6 or greater, unobstructed?

Comment: You can find many details in Sernesi's book *Deformations of algebraic schemes*, Example 3.2.11(i).

Comment: @Brenin Thanks! (For anyone else, the reference given says $h^1$ of the normal bundle vanishes ... and the result is true actually for degree greater 2 or greater).